# Packaging python code and including accessible configuration file

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

I am wondering what is the best approach to including a configuration file with a Python library I am packaging and making the configuration file accessible to users after installation. In my Python package I have a config.ini file with useful data such as file path shortcuts and user ID. I am searching for a way to include this configuration file with my Python package and have it be accessibly placed somewhere such as ~/MYPACKAGE/ so that after a user installs the package with pip they can edit the file path shortcuts. It seems one can add project data in their project.toml file

```
[tool.setuptools.package-data]
```

but I have not found a way to install package data to an accessible directory on a users machine.

Comment: Think about this scenario: the package is installed globally by root using `sudo pip install` and used by different non-root users; how do you expect `pip install` to install the config? Another scenario: two virtual environments like `python -m venv` for the same user; where should two copies of config be installed? The bottom line is: do not install configs at install time; install configs at run time and handle virtual environments.

Comment: On top of what @phd already said, I recommend you use this library to get the best locations to write configuration files: https://pypi.org/project/platformdirs/

Comment: Thank you @phd - I see your point. How then, would you recommend installing the configs at run time? Any examples you could point me to?

Comment: Something like this: https://blog.finxter.com/creating-reading-updating-a-config-file-with-python/ Found in https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&pws=0&q=python+install+config+at+runtime